# HTML5 Chrome supported popup Dialog box?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm wondering is there anyway of creating a dialog box for a Chrome extension using HTML5 or otherwise? basically I'd love to have a dialog box that looks more elegant than just creating a new window. Is there anything available to do so I'm attempting to create a popup effect.

Answer (score 1):

Challenge / Issue:

1) Chrome was not supporting windows popup

Reason:

Google Chrome no longer supports window.showModalDialog, breaking several enterprise apps such as OWA, EAC, SAP, and others.

Why:

1) Google decided to deprecate window.showModalDialog in Chrome 35 due to its related code complexity
 2) Google believe that showModalDialog is a “bad API” that, according to their measurements, is not used extensively

Immediate Solution:

The immediate solution is to switch to IE or Firefox. For those willing to stay on Chrome, one way to temporary solve this problem 
 is to enable this deprecated feature in Enterprise Policy settings, which can be done only until April 30, 2015
 (http://www.bugdebugzone.com/2014/08/sitecore-modal-pop-ups-are-not-working.html)

Another approach:

Another partial solution is using a ShowModalDialog polyfill as explained in this post, but some of the functionality 
 is still not restored.

Approach our team adapted:
 Work with Window.Open method and tweak the javascript code to adapt this method to refresh the parent window and pass values to and from.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to inject a <div> into the page and position / style it using CSS. [It is possible to include other JavaScript libraries with your plugin](http://blog.michael-forster.de/2009/08/using-jquery-to-build-google-chrome.html), so, you could look into using [jQuery UI's Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).